# Error: iisexpress.exe - Assertion failed

Tags: c#

I am trying to learn mvc. I use Pluralsight training videos in this site(asp.net).
In this video we created an `DBContext` Class called `OdeToFoodDb`:

```
public class OdeToFoodDb: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Review> Reviews { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Restaurant>()
            .HasMany(resturant => resturant.Reviews)
            .WithRequired(review => review.Resturant);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

The problem is when i create a new object of this class:

```
OdeToFoodDb _db = new OdeToFoodDb();
```

I get following error:

```
iisexpress.exe - Assertion failed.
Expression: primitiveType != null
Description: Assertion failed: primitiveType != null
```

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating EntityFramework to the latest version or use .NET4 for your project.

[This blog post might be related.](http://blog.luppes.com/2012/09/15/mvc3-application-failing-after-asp-net-4-5-install/)

Comment: Thank you. It works. But some namespace has been changed. Anyone who want to update, should consider that.
I updated entity framework version to 5.0.0.